# Change value in single linked list c++

Tags: c++

Hi guys can you spot what I'm doing wrong,

I need to check some If statment and if is true do a q++, then if my q is equal to 2 i need to delete and insert in place of my current value other value that is passed by user in c++ 98

edit here is url to my example im using vscode
http://cpp.sh/4qwwx

```cpp
 struct Shape{
    string name;
    int edges ;
    int area;
    Shape *next;
};

if (adr == NULL){
        cout << "empty list" <<endl;
        return;
    }
        
  
    Shape *prev  = adr;
    Shape *Shape = adr->next;
    int    q  = 0;
    int    edges;
    int    area;
    string name = "";
    
    while (prev != NULL && Shape != NULL){
        if (Shape->edges > prev->edges){
            q++;
            cout<< q <<endl;
        };
        if (q == 2){
                cout << "new name: ";
                cin  >> name;
                cout << "new edges: ";
                cin  >> edges;
                cout << "new area: ";
                cin  >> area;
                Shape->name  = name;
                Shape->edges = edges;
                Shape->area  = area;
                return;
        };

        free(Shape);
        prev = prev->next;
        if (prev != NULL)
            Shape = prev->next;
    }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information? Where is `adr` being set? I see a `free` statement but no `malloc`.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question with a link to cpp sh where you can find my code

Comment: kk, but im running it just fine in vscode this is c++ 98